Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: []
I use ubuntu 20.04 and ROS noetic. And, I want to connect Moveit with Gazebo simulation and Rviz. The robot model is auboi5 robot arm. I call /aubo_i5/controller_manager/list_controllers and the result is in the following.
controller: 
  - 
    name: "manipulator_i5_controller"
    state: "running"
    type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
    claimed_resources: 
      - 
        hardware_interface: "hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface"
        resources: 
          - foreArm_joint
          - shoulder_joint
          - upperArm_joint
          - wrist1_joint
          - wrist2_joint
          - wrist3_joint
  - 
    name: "gripper_controller"
    state: "running"
    type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
    claimed_resources: 
      - 
        hardware_interface: "hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface"
        resources: 
          - gripper_finger1_joint

But, when I press plan and execute button for one of the movegroups (i.e. manipulator_i5) in the Rviz, I got the following error message:
[ WARN] [1711986151.244228319, 9.694000000]: Failed to read controllers from /controller_manager/list_controllers
[ERROR] [1711984845.865042658, 780.646000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ foreArm_joint shoulder_joint upperArm_joint wrist1_joint wrist2_joint wrist3_joint ]
[ERROR] [1711986151.244323874, 9.694000000]: Known controllers and their joints:


This is my ros_controllers.yaml

aubo_i5:
  moveit_sim_hw_interface:
    joint_model_group: controllers_initial_group_
    joint_model_group_pose: controllers_initial_pose_

  generic_hw_control_loop:
    loop_hz: 300
    cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01

  hardware_interface:
    joints:
      - shoulder_joint
      - upperArm_joint
      - foreArm_joint
      - wrist1_joint
      - wrist2_joint
      - wrist3_joint
    sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity

  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50

  manipulator_i5_controller: 
    type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
    joints: 
      - shoulder_joint
      - upperArm_joint
      - foreArm_joint
      - wrist1_joint
      - wrist2_joint
      - wrist3_joint
    gains:
      shoulder_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
      upperArm_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
      foreArm_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
      wrist1_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
      wrist2_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
      wrist3_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}

  gripper_controller: 
    type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
    joints: 
        - gripper_finger1_joint
    gains:
      gripper_finger1_joint: {p: 100, d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}

controller_list:
  - name: aubo_i5/manipulator_i5_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints: 
      - shoulder_joint
      - upperArm_joint
      - foreArm_joint
      - wrist1_joint
      - wrist2_joint
      - wrist3_joint
      
  - name: aubo_i5/gripper_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints: 
      - gripper_finger1_joint

This is my ros_controllers.launch:


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- Load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" ns="/aubo_i5" output="screen" 
    args="--namespace=/aubo_i5 
    manipulator_i5_controller 
    gripper_controller 
    --timeout 30"/>

</launch>

This is ros_control_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml
<launch>
    <!-- Define MoveIt controller manager plugin -->
    <param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="moveit_ros_control_interface::MoveItControllerManager" />
    <rosparam file="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml"/>
</launch>

This is my demo_gazebo.launch

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- MoveIt options -->
  <arg name="pipeline" default="ompl" doc="Planning pipeline to use with MoveIt"/>

  <arg name="use_gui" default="false" />
  
  <!-- By default, we are not in debug mode -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false" />

  <!-- By default, we won't load or override the robot_description -->
  <arg name="load_robot_description" default="true"/>

  <!-- Gazebo options -->
  <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="true" doc="Start Gazebo GUI"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Start Gazebo paused"/>
  <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world" doc="Gazebo world file"/>
  <arg name="world_pose" default="-x 0 -y 0 -z 0 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0" doc="Pose to spawn the robot at"/>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" unless="$(arg use_gui)">
<!-- <rosparam param="source_list">[move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam> -->
<rosparam param="source_list">[aubo_i5/joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>  
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" if="$(arg use_gui)">
    <!-- <rosparam param="source_list">[move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam> -->
    <rosparam param="source_list">[aubo_i5/joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <!-- Launch Gazebo and spawn the robot -->
  <include file="$(dirname)/gazebo.launch" pass_all_args="true"/>

  <!-- Run the main MoveIt! executable without trajectory execution (we do not have controllers configured by default) -->
  <include file="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
<arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="true"/>
<arg name="info" value="true"/>
<arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="$(arg load_robot_description)"/>
    <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" value="ros_control" />
  </include>  

  <!-- Run Rviz and load the default config to see the state of the move_group node -->
  <include file="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
<arg name="rviz_config" value="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/launch/moveit.rviz"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

</launch>

This is gazebo.launch
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Gazebo options -->
  <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="true" doc="Start Gazebo GUI"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Start Gazebo paused"/>
  <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world" doc="Gazebo world file"/>
  <arg name="world_pose" default="-x 0 -y 0 -z 0 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0" doc="Pose to spawn the robot at"/>
  <arg name="initial_joint_positions" default=" -J foreArm_joint 0 -J shoulder_joint 0 -J upperArm_joint 0 -J wrist1_joint 0 -J wrist2_joint 0 -J wrist3_joint 0" doc="Initial joint configuration of the robot"/>

  <!-- Start Gazebo paused to allow the controllers to pickup the initial pose -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch" pass_all_args="true">
    <arg name="paused" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Set the robot urdf on the parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/config/gazebo_aubo_i5.urdf" />

  <!-- Unpause the simulation after loading the robot model -->
  <arg name="unpause" value="$(eval '' if arg('paused') else '-unpause')" />

  <!-- Spawn the robot in Gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot $(arg unpause) $(arg world_pose) $(arg initial_joint_positions)"
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <!-- Load the controller parameters onto the parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find aubo_i5_gripper_moveit_config)/config/gazebo_controllers.yaml" />
  <include file="$(dirname)/aubo_i5_controllers.launch"/>

  <!-- Spawn the Gazebo ROS controllers -->
  <node name="gazebo_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="joint_state_controller" />

  <!-- Given the published joint states, publish tf for the robot links -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen">
      <remap from="/joint_states" to="aubo_i5/joint_states" />
  </node>
</launch>


I have spent many hours on how to configure it but still cannot get it work and really have no clues. Any advice would be appreciated.
